# What is the recommended way to handle this issue? Mobile HTML5

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova, mobile

I am building a Cordova application with jQuery Mobile

My application displays a bunch of words for the user in an array using a for loop

```
 <div id=page1div></div>
 <script>
 $page1div = $("#page1div");

 // some codes here to make the array

 function filltheRecentDivGenerate()  
 {
    var list = " "; var len = results.length; 

    for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
         list =+ " <h1> "+ results[i] + " </h1> ";
     }

 $page1div.html(list);
 }
 </script>
```

And it only displays the first seven.  There are many more after the first seven, but the screen only lets the user view the first seven because it reaches the bottom of the screen by the time it displays the 7th word.

What is the best way to enable the user to view all of them?  Thanks!

If it is enabling scrolling down, then could you show me how?  I tried listview but it did not enable me to see the words after the 7th and it was rather disastrous

Comment: append them to `<div role="main" class="ui-content">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function filltheRecentDivGenerate()  
 {
    var list = " "; var len = results.length; 

    for (var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        $('.ui-content').append("<h1> "+ results[i] + " </h1>");
    }
 }

</script>
```